# Popular question from 2009 with obsolete answer

Tags: discussion, outdated-information

[How to use wikipedia api if it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964454/how-to-use-wikipedia-api-if-it-exists) is the [most frequent MediaWiki question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki?sort=frequent). Asked in 2009, it has had almost 40k views so far.

MediaWiki cares a lot about promoting usage of the API; in fact, every Wikipedia and Wikimedia page now links the [How to contribute](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/How_to_contribute) page in the footer. I don't know how many of those 40k views are recent and perhaps I should disregard them as [that page has 260k per month](http://stats.grok.se/www.w/latest30/How_to_contribute), but I think the question deserves a good answer.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964597/1333493) is obsoleted by a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14857668/13334939) which – while minimal – provides the only good entry point for newbies, ApiSandbox, as well as docs. ApiSandbox was introduced in 2011/2012. How to put such an answer (or similar) near the top?

I placed a 300 rep bounty but it was ignored, I only lost my reputation. Overcoming 66 votes of difference is going to take ages. Flagging the obsolete answer seems excessive (it's a legit answer).

Comment: Did you consider *editing* the answer to bring it up to date?

Comment: For the bounty, what do you mean by "it was ignored"? Did you actually *award* the bounty to the answer you like?

Comment: On the plus side - it was a 300 bounty - so you're 200 more than you thought you were :) - In all seriousness though, as long as you're not putting words into people's mouths/changing intent etc... posts are a community effort - feel free to edit/add a comment/etc...

Comment: @Oded - In fairness I'd probably reject that edit as an attempt to reply, unless I saw a comment showing that there was at least some attempt to let the user update their post. The answerer's profile shows that they were active a few days ago, and there's no comment on the answer asking them to update it, or specify that it only applies to version X of the software. But I probably reject too many edits.

Comment: Now its closed as "too broad". A good example of why too broad questions are unwelcome I'd say; the answers are a dated mess of haphazard chunks of information with no real indication what is really relevant or not, the more adequate answer is snowed under and all this requires an unsung hero of SO to try and put some order to the madness.

Comment: I mean that the bounty did not cause any new answer to be posted and I lost the reputation because I forgot to manually award it to a past answer. Sorry for misremembering the amount. :/ I guess it's legit to close the question, but I still wonder how to give better info to the people arriving there.

Comment: To be honest, those people should be reading the readily available manual already. You can't and should not try to cater to people who refuse to do even the most basic research.